# How to modify year with a Cast Statement in Sql

Tags: sql, casting

I would like to get some help with a `CAST` SQL Statement
From the below table sample, I would like to modify only the year from 2008 to 2016. Please keep in mind that I need this done with `CAST`, and not with `DATEADD`.

[image]

Comment: So you want to cast the date as a varchar, then use string functions to replace the year part with 2016?  Why can't you use date functions again?

Answer (score 1):

DATEADD(YEAR, 8, DATE) would be the solution but if that is not an option please utilize one of the following options.

I have left the DATEADD options in there in case they are usable after all.

```
   DECLARE @d_date DATE = '2008-07-01'
   DECLARE @v_date VARCHAR(25) = '2008-07-01'


   SELECT @d_date,
          @v_date,
          DATEADD(YEAR, 8, @d_date),
          DATEADD(YEAR, 8, CONVERT(DATE, @v_date)),
          DATEADD(YEAR, 8, CAST(@v_date AS DATE)),
          CAST(CAST(LEFT(@v_date, 4) AS NUMERIC) + 8 AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT(@v_date, LEN(@v_date) - 4)
```

Please do not use the last one.

An example of Code.

http://rextester.com/NHHL75120